# Stream filter in cuda

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia

I have an array of values and a linked list of indexes. Now, i only want to keep those values from the array that correspond to the indexes in the LL. is there a standard algorithm to do this. Please give example if possible

So, suppose i have an array 1,2,5,6,7,9
and i have a linked list 2->3

So, i want to keep the values at the index 2 and 3. That is keep 5 and 6.
Thus my function should return 5 and 6

Comment: Not clear what you want to do exactly - you should probably post some normal scalar code in C that does what you want and then it may be possible to tell you how to implement this in CUDA.

Comment: Are the entries in the linked list guaranteed to be ordered in some predictable way (like sorted) ?

Comment: @talonmies: Yes, the index are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

In general, linked list is inherently serial. Having a parallel machine will not speed up the traversal of your list, hence the number of steps of your problem cannot go below O(n), where n is the size of the list.

However, if you have some additional way to access the list you can do something with it.
For example, all elements of the list could be stored in a fixed-size array (although, not necesairly in a consecutive way). List member could be represented in an array using the following struct.

```
struct ListNode {
    bool isValid;
    T data;
    int next;
}
```

The value `isValid` sets if given cell in an array is occupied by a valid list member, or it is just an empty cell.

Now, a parallel algorithm would read all cells at once, check if it represents a valid data, and if so, do something with it.

Second part: Each thread, having a valid index `idx` of your input array `A` would have to mark `A[idx]` not to be deleted. Once we know which elements of `A` should be removed and which not - a parallel compaction algorithm can be applied.